# What is the Android widget type used in e.g. the Settings menu?

Tags: android

The Android settings menu is a list of options, each with some subtext (in the vanilla Google implementation; not in Sense UI) and an image (a down arrow in vanilla, custom icons in Sense UI). They are selectable and open a sub menu (Activity?) when clicked, like a button.

What is this widget? Is it available in the `android.widget` package somewhere? Is there a way to simulate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good thing about Android is that it is Open Source, i.e. you can get the source code and find the answers to questions like this one. You don't even need to install Git and download the entire code base - it is all conveniently available and searchable online.

Start [here](http://source.android.com/source/download.html).

(I think it is a ListView with custom rows)

Comment: It does seem to be a ListView; this is what I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for, [Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) and [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html).